# Calculating the result of a recurrence function

Tags: c++, time-limit-exceeded, mathematics

The recurrence function is defined as follows:

- \$f(0) = 1\$
- \$f(1) = 1\$
- \$f(2n) = f(n)\$
- \$f(2n+1) = f(n) + f(n-1)\$

I was tasked to calculate the recurrence of a very large number, \$n = 66666666666666\$, using C++. As you can clearly see, the 3rd line applies for even inputs, and the 4th line for odd inputs. If this isn't clear consider the following derivation for \$f(10)\$:

\$f(10) = f(5) = f(2) + f(1) = f(1) + f(1) = 1 + 1 = 2\$

---

```
long long int function(long long int x) {
  if (x == 0 || x == 1) 
      return 1; 

  long long int result = 0;

  if (x % 2 != 0) {
      result += function((x-1)/2) + function((x/2)-1);
  } else {
      result += function(x/2);
  }

  return result;
}
```

The runtime of this implementation is very large (almost 30 seconds to finish). Clearly this is because recursion is very expensive. My runtime limit is 1.0s, at most. Therefore I think an iterative approach would work wonders.

This is the result of running `time ./my_program`:

> ```
> real  0m29.893s
> user  0m29.809s
> sys   0m0.075s
> ```

I am wondering if there are other approaches, besides translating it to an iterative version, which would be suitable for this problem in particular. I would also be grateful if anyone has any pointers about my code/approach.

Comment: Broken code close vote without explanation: I have voted to leave open.

Comment: @Pimgd there was a typo in my code which I fixed last night

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Avoid the `result` variable

The `result` variable is only ever incremented once and then returned. You can simplify by returning directly:

```
if (x % 2 != 0) { 
  return function((x-1)/2) + function((x/2)-1); 
} else { 
  return function(x/2);
}
```

Eliminating the variable should also speed-up the program if the compiler did not optimize it out already.

#### Memoization

Memoization essentially stores already computed values for later re-use trading space for run-time. [Memoization has already been implemented in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17805969/3105485) so you can just make use of it.

Comment: @ialcuaz memoization is essentially to help recursion. Successive calls do not need recalculation.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I've posted what the final code looks like below, thanks for reminding me to use dynamic programming

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the c++ file on me, but if anyone is interested in what the final program looks like, here is what it essentially looks like in pseudocode. Thanks @Caridorc for suggesting a memoization procedure. It is easily translatable to c++:

```
Function f(n):
  if n is either of the two base cases, return 1 

  let M be the memoization table

  if n is cached: 
    return M[n]

  if n is not cached:
    if n is even:
      M[n] = f(n/2);   

    if n is odd:
      M[n] = f((n-1)/2) + f((n/2)-1);

  return M[n]
```

I screenshot-ed the new execution time:

[image]